# Pass history as props to an event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am creating a form which after being filled up and the submit button is clicked should navigate to another component. However, I cant seem to be able to pass history as a prop. I assume I am doing something wrong with the bindings of this but cant figure this out. Thanks.

Here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {LandingPage} from './landingPage/LandingPage';
import {ReportsPage} from './reportsPage/ReportsPage';

export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter >
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage}/>
          <Route path="/reports"
             render={() => <ReportsPage/>} 
          />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my LandingPage.js

```
export class LandingPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    ...
    this.formAnswersUpdater = this.formAnswersUpdater.bind(this)
  }

  formAnswersUpdater(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    ...
    history.push("/reports")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <MyForm
          onClickOnLastInputsForm={e => this.formAnswersUpdater}
        />
      </div>
     )
   }
```

And here is where my event is happening. MyForm.js

```
export class MyForm extends React.Component {
render() {
  return(
    ...
    <Route render={({history}) => (
      <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-width-1-1@s"
              style={{backgroundColor:'#41f44f',
                      color:'#666', margin: 0}}
              id='buttonSliders'
              /*if done here it works*/
              /*onClick={() => {history.push("/reports")}}*/
              /*However if passed to the event handler it does not*/
              onClick={() => {this.props.onClickOnLastInputsForm}}
      >
        ClickMe!
      </button>
    )}/>
  )
```

My react-router-dom version is: "^4.2.2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is how I handled the issue.

Instead of exporting the LandingPage component, I wrapped it in withRouter function and then exported it.

```
class LandingPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    ...
    this.formAnswersUpdater = this.formAnswersUpdater.bind(this)
  }

  formAnswersUpdater(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    ...
    //added this.props. here
    this.props.history.push("/reports")
  }



render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <MyForm
          onClickOnLastInputsForm={e => this.formAnswersUpdater}
        />
      </div>
     )
}
// wrapped it with withRouter
export default withRouter(LandingPage)
```

And then in MyForm component I just called the eventHandler.

```
export class MyForm extends React.Component {
render() {
  return(
    ...
      <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-width-1-1@s"
              style={{backgroundColor:'#41f44f',
                      color:'#666', margin: 0}}
              id='buttonSliders'
              onClick={this.props.onClickOnLastInputsForm()}
      >
        ClickMe!
      </button>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve all of your problems, but I see something important missing in your `LandingPage` render function

```
onClickOnLastInputsForm={e => this.formAnswersUpdater}
```

You forgot to pass in your argument: `e`

```
onClickOnLastInputsForm={e => this.formAnswersUpdater(e)}
```

Make sure you add this on `MyForm` as well. You forgot it there as well. Do you get any other errors after fixing those?

edit: After some inspection of the docs, it looks like the typical use of `react-router-dom` has a different pattern than what you have. Most common pattern with route handling is to have a root set of routes and use `Link` from the npm package to navigate. I only see history and its derivatives in the docs for `react-router`. I'm aware that `react-router-dom` is a derivative of `react-router`, but I think if you follow the normal patterns for React, it'll be a lot easier for you in the future when you're debugging.

A nice article on it. It even has a sample app using it: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

Comment: this.formAnswersUpdater actually does several things before pushing to history and I have tried to window.log them and they all work(including looking at the event object) if I am not pushing to history. Therefore the event is transfered. Furthermore, I have also tried e => this.formAnswersUpdater(e) ; e => this.formAnswersUpdater() ; and {this.formAnswersUpdater}; and the only one that is working properly (except for the history.push part) is the one provided in the question.

Comment: @deann I looked into the docs for everything and the recap is this: If you do it the same way as everybody else does, your life is going to  be a lot easier.